# Definite integral involving square root of polynomial

Tags: definite-integrals

How can I solve the integral below?

$$\int_0^1 (x^4+x^3+x^2+x^1+1)^{1/2} \mathrm dx $$

Comment: I've edited the question and made the title more explicit. Make sure it still reflected what you wanted.

Comment: Where did you encounter this integral?

Comment: Either way, it can't be done in terms of elementary functions. I have seen this question on a different forum. In a book I have seen it where students had to apply Simpson Rule

Comment: When you want to extract arc length from the a cubic Bezier curve you will face such an Integral.......

Comment: The Maple code $$with(Student[Calculus1]):evalf(ApproximateInt(sqrt(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1), x = 0 .. 1, method = simpson)) $$ produces $1.468637500$ and $$int(sqrt(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1), x = 0 .. 1, numeric, epsilon = 0.1e-1) $$ gives $ 1.468637565.$

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to Maple, is any Matlab code for it?? Is it possible for you to let me know how is it solved, with which algorithm?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to Maple, is any Matlab code for it?? Is it possible for you to let me know how is it solved, with which algorithm?

Comment: @MahsaGhaffari Any numerical quadrature algorithm will work, for example Simpson's rule. In Matlab, just use `integral`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html

Comment: @Mahsa Ghaffari: Also one can use [the WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=calculate+the+integral+of+sqrt%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%29+from+0+to+1) to this end.

Comment: @MahsaGhaffari : you don't solve definite integrals, you evaluate them.  I would recommend trying a computing algebra system first to see if it is even possible.  wolframalpha.com is is free and online.  All you need is an Internet connection and a Web browser. It seems to accept Mathematica or Maple syntax, at least.  In Maplese, you enter int(sqrt(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1),x=0..1) in the box.  If you don't get an exact answer, it probably cannot be done exactly using named functions.  wolframalpha will probably give you an approximate answer whether or not it can do it exactly.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the horrible result of calculating $\int(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)^\frac{1}{2}~dx$ by [Wolfram Integrator](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=%28x%5E4%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%2B1%29%5E%281%2F2%29&random=false), but I have the following relatively simpler approach:

$\int_0^1(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)^\frac{1}{2}~dx$

$=\int_0^1\left(\dfrac{1-x^5}{1-x}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}~dx$

$=\int_0^1\dfrac{(1-x^5)^\frac{1}{2}}{(1-x)^\frac{1}{2}}~dx$

$=\int_0^1\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2n)!x^{5n}}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)(1-x)^\frac{1}{2}}dx$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2n)!B\left(5n+1,\dfrac{1}{2}\right)}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2n)!(5n)!\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)!}{4^n(n!)^2\left(5n+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)!(1-2n)}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2n)!(5n)!\sqrt\pi}{4^n(n!)^2\dfrac{(10n)!\sqrt\pi}{4^{5n}(5n)!}(1-2n)}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{256^n(2n)!((5n)!)^2}{(n!)^2(10n)!(1-2n)}$

Comment: (+1) This result/method can also be expressed in terms of the [generalised hypergeometric function][1]: $$\int _{0}^{1}\!\sqrt {{\frac {{x}^{5}-1}{x-1}}}{dx}=2\,
{\mbox{$_6$F$_5$}(-\frac {1}{2},\frac {1}{5},\frac {2}{5},\frac {3}{10},\frac {4}{5},1;\,\frac {3}{10},\frac {1}{2},{\frac {7}{10}},{\frac {9}{10}},{\frac {11}{10}};\,1)}$$
not that that neccessarily adds much.


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function

Comment: @ Harry Peter: Up to [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression), this is not a closed-form expression

Comment: @ Graham Heskesh: Could you base your claim?

Comment: @user64494, the series can be written as a single summation, the summand can be expressed in terms of the pochhammer symbol and that series can be compared to the series for the generalised hypergeometric function (see e.g. Maple help "hypergeom") some algebra is involved to get a recognisable comparison, this might be of academic interest but I don't think it adds much in this context.